# Viewing events count grouped by taxonomy terms on Calendar

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, datetime

I am trying to view a count of events for each "event type", which is taxonomy field, using calendar but I am totally lost! Here is what I have done:

1. Created a "Event types" vocabulary and added terms like "Conference", "Journal" etc.
2. Created a "Event" content type with a term reference to "Event types", plus and a start date/time.
3. Created a new "view content" view, with type = "Event", displayed as a "Calendar" with fields.
4. Added the "start date field" as a contextual filter
5. Added "Nid" and the "Event Type" fields, and set "use aggregation" to true
6. Set the "Nid" to Count Distinct and "event type" to Group By.

However, using "Format->Display Fields" shows nothing! So I tried to use display as "Calendar Items" and display as "Calendar Entities" but, instead of showing the events count for each event type, it shows the events and and 1 as count.

Any idea about the problem or help on how to achieve what I am looking is very welcome.

Comment: May be my question is more like "How to show taxonomy terms on Calendar according to the date terms were referenced?"